# Error when trying to build html from json with redoc-build (JSON generated in Swagger)

Tags: api, npm, swagger, openapi, redoc

I created a documentation in Swagger and I am trying to convert the json to html with redoc (from npm).

When I enter this command:

```
redoc-cli bundle -o index.html swagger.json
```

I get this error :

[image: This is the error !]

How can I solve this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your swagger.json file so that others can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

redoc-cli bundle swagger.json -o index.html